# Trying to register a plugin in Zend framework 1 - white screen, no errors logged

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've put the following in my Bootstrap.php file:

```
protected function _initPlugins()
{
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getinstance();

    $front->registerPlugin(new QA_Plugins_SamlPassiveLogin());
}
```

Here is my plugin:

```
class QA_Plugins_SamlPassiveLogin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {

    }

    public function dispatchLoopShutdown()
    {

    }
}
```

As you can see the plugin doesn't do much at the moment, I just wanted to test that it was registering. But, even as it is now and I load the page the screen is blank with no errors. If I check the error log for fatal errors - nothing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `QA` is a library or your application? And is there something in the code source?

Comment: Yeh the QA_ class are loaded with composer (configured in composer, to PSR-0 autoload classes within the application/library directory -- this class path is application/library/QA/Plugins/SamlPassiveLogin.php). The class is being accessed OK as it was throwing an error when I hadn't named it correctly. Anyway, if it couldn't find the class it would throw an exception which it doesn't. How do you mean something in the code source? Currently the methods are empty as above, I'm just at this stage trying to confirm that the plugin is registered before writing the code that the plugin will run.

Comment: Yes, I make few tests and each time, I had exceptions...